SBOM tracking that shows version in use, most recent LTS and most recent released versions of software?
One of the things I've been asked to provide is a high level dependency track that shows the current version in use against the LTS and most recent release versions. Most tooling I can find, like Dependency Track, just shows against CVE's.
Is there a tool that can do this? I don't mind generating our own CycloneDX BOM's. This will sourced from containers. We're talking about tracking JDK's, Ruby, Node, Tomcat. So high level dependencies. Not the specific dev dependencies.
